# how to get rid of the light blue boundary line

Tags: pictures

[image]

I have been having problems to getting rid of that outer blue border because it keeps on hiding other objects when inserting text, images, and shapes...
please send help

Comment: Welcome Luigi! Your question is exceptionally unclear - 1) What software are you using? 2) Which "blue line" the bounding box or the outer line? 3) What is the outer line? An artboard, a guide, a clipping mask shape?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.